# how to store form data in an array using session?

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have to store form data i.e. Roll No and Marks of a student in an array using session.
When I am doing this, the previous value is overwritten by the new value after submitting form.
I want to add the value in array next to the previous value with a new index.

Here is my form

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    Roll No:<input type="text" name="rollno" value="" id="rollno"  />
    Marks:<input type="text" name="marks" value="" id="marks"  />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validate();" />
</form>
```

and

```
<?php
session_start();
//session_destroy();
$_SESSION['status'] = array();

$_SESSION['status'][] = @$_POST['rollno'];
$_SESSION['status'][] = @$_POST['marks'];

print_r($_SESSION['status']);                    
?>
```

How can I do this please help me?

Comment: Can you explain where exactly you want to add new data ? next is a bit ambiguous. Add an example of previous and new state of array.

Comment: Is it `Roll No` or `Row No`?

Comment: Use `isset` to check whether a variable is set instead of suppressing the notice using `@`.

Comment: Do you mean store to database? why did you use 'mysql' tag?

Answer (score 1):

This is a way...

```
<?php
session_start();
$i=0;

while(isset($_SESSION[$i])) $i++;

$_SESSION[$i]['rollno'] = $_POST['rollno'];
$_SESSION[$i]['marks'] = $_POST['marks'];
-
-
-
?>
```

Comment: hello sir, thanks for replying but it is not working. Actually I have to insert 10 student records one by one in form and also display the output on the same page. when I add first student record then it display the output but when I insert second student record it display only second student record . I want to display previous record also.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a serialized array to a session like this:

```
$_SESSION['key'] = serialize($yourArray);
```

Then when you want to add something, just unserialize it, modify and put it back in your session.

Answer (score 0):

i will explain with a sample

```
  <?php
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['data']= array();
    $details1=array('pappu','10');
    $details2=array('tippu','12');

    array_push($_SESSION['data'],$details1);
    array_push($_SESSION['data'],$details2);

    foreach ($_SESSION['data'] as $eacharray) {
    while (list(, $value) = each ($eacharray)) {
        echo "Value: $value<br>\n";
    }
    }

?>
```

*output*

> Value: pappu
>  Value: 10 
> Value: tippu 
> Value: 12

**you can try**

```
 $rollArray=array($_POST['rollno'],$_POST['marks']);
 array_push($_SESSION['status'], $rollArray);


 foreach ($_SESSION['status'] as $eacharray) {
    while (list(, $value) = each ($eacharray)) {
        echo "Value: $value<br>\n";
    }
    }
```

Comment: hello sir, thanks for replying but it is not working. Actually I have to insert 10 student records one by one in form and also display the output on the same page. when I add first student record then it display the output but when I insert second student record it display only second student record . I want to display previous record also.